# Tableau: Finding an attribute count from ONLY distinct rows

Tags: tableau-api

I can't seem to find a solution for my issue anywhere, and I hope that I can ask my question correctly here to find an answer:

> I am having a problem finding a count of the number of values from only the distinct rows in my dataset.

In my Tableau sheet, I am trying to find the number of cases that are closed as "FCR" - and in the database, this is represented as true or false.

My formula:

```
SUM(if [IsFCR] = true then 1 else 0 end)
```

The problem that I am running into is that this is getting the count from all of the rows in my data.  But I need represent the total cases, and the FCR value from each of THOSE rows as a distinct count.

As seen in this image: [Screen capture of Tableau formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOzNR.png)
I am returning 9,000 distinct rows - but 46,000 counts of FCR being true.

Notably, I have tried wrapping my formula in a COUNTD (and it returns 2), in Window_Count (returns 1), among many other guesses as to how I could wrap this calculated field in a way to only count the unique rows.

If only I could use a `foreach` logic...

Any help that you can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having bumped into one our Tableau Developer pros (who happened to be here late catching up on some work) we finally found a solution to this:I still needed the

Comment: Sorry, issues with the edit:    I still needed the COUNTD - but on my if statement I needed to count the row if true.  Lastly, I needed to initialize to 0 (thus a -1 was needed)  Like so: `COUNTD(if [IsFCR] = true then [ID] else 0 end)-1`    And [here you can see it in action](http://i.imgur.com/E045m5F.png)